# Getting past a login page in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, web-scraping, request

For some reason I cannot get my head around using the requests.Session() function to save login credentials. My current code isn't working and I cannot figure out why, can someone help correct my code and explain the changes that were needed? I don't want to keep asking for help on a website by website basis.

```
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'text/html',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36',
    'origin':'https://stockinvest.us',
    'referer':'https://stockinvest.us'
    }
data = {'email':'user-email', 'password: 'user-password'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    login = s.post('https://stockinvest.us/login', data=data, headers=headers)
    s.cookies
    r = s.get('https://stockinvest.us/profile/edit')
```

Comment: why not try to use cookies they tend to work

Comment: You are saying I should add `s.cookies` ? I tried that and I am still not getting past the login page.

Comment: yes you should use s.cookies